# Cumulative quantity of type X products in javascript

Tags: arrays, dictionary, ecmascript-6, reduce

This is the case: Every order can contain many types, with different quantities. I want, for each order item, the total quantity for each type.

```
[{
  "order" : 1,
  "orderDetails" : [{
    "quantity" : 10,
    "product" : {
      "productType" : "A"
    },
    "quantity" : 20,
    "product" : {
      "productType" : "A"
    },
    "quantity" : 10,
    "product" : {
      "productType" : "B"
    }
  }]
}]
```

this is my code, it does the job but I am trying to make it a bit more elegant, somehow. I am pretty sure there is redundant code there, I am not sure I am using reduce correctly

```
    const orders = data.map(h => {
    const newArray = [];
    h.orderDetails_ = h.orderDetails.reduce(function(a, b, i) {
        if (newArray[b.product.productType] == undefined) {
          newArray[b.product.productType] = b.quantity;
          return newArray;  
        } else {
          newArray[b.product.productType] += b.quantity;
          return newArray;
        }
      }, 0);
      return h;
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

well, for anyone out there, this is the better and correct version

```
    const orders = data.map(h => {
      h.orderDetails_ = h.orderDetails.reduce((orderTotals, order) => {
        orderTotals[order.product.productType] =
          (orderTotals[order.product.productType] || 0) + order.quantity;
        return orderTotals;
      }, {});
      return h;
    });
```